# Kong Mocking plugin response custom headers

Tags: mocking, header, response, kong, kong-plugin

can I use Mocking plugin to return custom headers?
I tried it out but did not succeed.
I specified headers in the openapi specification like below but never received StudyId headers in response.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: mock
  description: This API is intended to 
  contact:
    email: mock@mail.com
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://dummy-apispec.com
tags:
  - name: Data
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          headers:
            StudyId:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: studyId1
          content:
            application/json:
              example:
                message: 'hello'
```

I expect to receive custom header from Mocking plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In Kong, you can add the "Request Transformer" plugin to return custom headers.

Comment: Yes, but by using mock I want to emulate upstream service behavior that is supposed to return custom header. I do not want to use request transformer since it will continue to add custom header even when mock is disabled. Your suggestion may help, but I must be sure that both plugins (mock and transformer) are enabled and disabled synchronously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).